# How to fix CSS Animation for Safari Browser

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I made a simple animation with typing effect for a script:

```
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 ;}
  to { width: 90% ; border: 0;}
}

@keyframes console {
  from { height: 0 }
  to { height: 100% }
}

@keyframes opacityS {
  0% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 100%}
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}

.typewriter{
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .05em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono", serif;
  animation:
          typing 1.5s steps(40) 0s forwards,
          0.2s opacityS 0s forwards,
          blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
  animation-delay: var(--delay);
}
```

here is my TSX file:

```
 <Box sx={{
                           whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                           fontFamily: "IBM Plex Mono",
                           fontWeight: "400",
                           fontStyle: "normal",
                           fontSize: "12px !important",
                           lineHeight: "158%",
                           letterSpacing: ".15em",
                           color: palette.white,
                           "span": {
                               whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                               fontFamily: "IBM Plex Mono",
                               fontWeight: "400",
                               fontStyle: "normal",
                               fontSize: "12px !important",
                               lineHeight: "158%",
                               color: palette.white,
                           },
                       }}>

                           <Box className={"hidden"} ref={scriptDiv1}>
                              <Box sx={{
                                  width: "100%",
                                  height: "fit-content",
                                  fontSize: "12px !important",
                              }}>
                                  <Box className={"typewriter"} sx={{
                                      float: "left",
                                      fontSize: "12px !important",
                                  }}>
                                      <span style={{color: "#8CA0FF"}}>const</span>

                                      {'  secretpay = '}

                                      <span style={{color: "#00E2FF"}}>require</span>

                                      {'('}

                                      <span style={{color: "#FFAA57"}}>‘secretpay’</span>

                                      {')('}

                                      <span style={{color: "#FFAA57"}}>{'‘sk_test_B!okht39fH21jg0J12oiqg'}</span>
                                  </Box>
                              </Box>

                               <br/>
                               <br/>

                               <Box sx={{
                                   width: "100%",
                                   height: "fit-content",
                                   fontSize: "12px !important",
                               }}>
                                   <Box className={"typewriter"} sx={{
                                       float: "left",
                                       "--delay": "1.5s",
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       width: "55%",
                                   }}>

                                       <span style={{color: "#8CA0FF"}}>await</span>

                                       {' secretpay.paymentIntents.'}

                                       <span style={{color: "#00E2FF"}}>create</span>
                                       {'({'}

                                   </Box>
                               </Box>

                               <br/>

                               <Box sx={{
                                   width: "100%",
                                   height: "fit-content",
                                   fontSize: "12px !important",
                               }}>
                                   <Box className={"typewriter"} sx={{
                                       float:"left",
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       "--delay": "2.5s",
                                       width: "30%"
                                   }}>

                                       {'amount: '}

                                       <span style={{color: "#FFDD1A"}}>2000</span>

                                       ,

                                   </Box>
                               </Box>

                               <br/>

                               <Box sx={{
                                   width: "100%",
                                   height: "fit-content",
                                   fontSize: "12px !important",
                               }}>
                                   <Box className={"typewriter"} sx={{
                                       float:"left",
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       "--delay": "3.2s",
                                       width: "30%"
                                   }}>

                                       {'currency: '}

                                       <span style={{color: "#FFAA57"}}>‘usd’</span>

                                   </Box>
                               </Box>

                               <br/>

                               <Box sx={{
                                   width: "100%",
                                   height: "fit-content",
                                   fontSize: "12px !important",
                               }}>
                                   <Box className={"typewriter"} sx={{
                                       float:"left",
                                       opacity: 0,
                                       "--delay": "4s",
                                       width: "15%"
                                   }}>

                                       {'});|'}

                                   </Box>
                               </Box>



                           </Box>
                           </Box>
```

how its looks like:
[image]

how animation looks like on chrome:

[image]

And how it looks like on safari (In our case on Iphone, on macs animations works without problems)

[image]

The animation looks broken only on iphones.
I cant spot the problem. My project uses NextJS + TS + MaterialUI v5.
If you have any ideas feel free to share it with me , thanks in advance.